# Media queries: Three external CSS files

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm creating a website and have successfully created media queries with external CSS files for both mobile and desktop styling. You can see the HTML below linking to the external sheets; mobile.css is used on devices <767px and desktop.css is used on devices >768px.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="css/desktop.css" />
</head>
```

Having designed the site, I believe I can make this more responsive and would like to change desktop.css to tablet.css and create a new desktop.css for devices over 1000px. Linking the below external CSS with media queries doesn't work though:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" href="css/mobile.css" /> <!-- This works fine -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="css/tablet.css" /> <!-- This works fine -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)" href="css/desktop.css" /> <!-- Doesn't work -->
</head>
```

The above produces mobile.css working correctly and tablet.css correctly but it just keeps tablet.css when it goes over 1000px rather than applying desktop.css.

My question is would I go about adding a third CSS file for devices over 1000px?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Philpot

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks to the answer from Daniel Wiecek, it's pointed me in the right direction and I've figured it out. To have three CSS external files for mobile, tablet and desktop, the below HTML worked:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px)" href="css/tablet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)" href="css/desktop.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't know the method exactly, but how about this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px)" href="css/tablet.css" />
```

or

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px,max-width: 999px)" href="css/tablet.css" />
```